# Passing input value to another page using $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, input

I tried to passing the input value from user to another page by using the Session method after the user click on submit button.

My page has a form with one button which called as "Add Textbox". This button allow the user to add textbox by themselves.

Here is my current code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function() {

    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 2) {
      alert("System required at least one.");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
  <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label>Textbox #1 :</label>
      <input type='textbox' id='textbox1' name="textbox1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

And here is my code to assign the value to session in php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
            {
                if(isset($_POST['textbox'.$i]))
                {
                    $obj = $_POST['textbox'.$i];
                    echo $obj,'<br>';
                    $_SESSION['textbox'.$i] = $obj;
                }
            }
            header("Location:../brightan-system/result.php");
       }
    ?>
```

and here is how I tried to get the value from the second page

```
<?php
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
    {
        echo "<strong>".$i."</strong> ".$_SESSION['textbox'.$i]."<br>";//Use the session variables
    }
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Actually, I can get a result on the second page, but the problem is if the user only add 4 textboxes, then there will be an error that said Undefined index on the second page. This is because the for loop produce 10 session variable on the second page.

Is there another way to get the session variable instead using for loop in this case?

Comment: Instead of setting input name with counter, you can simply use ``<input type="text" name="textbox[]'``.  On php side you can use ``count($post['textbox'])`` to get the count of text boxes and use this count in loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check first if ith textbox is set or not. Add condition to check before printing it.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
  if(isset($_SESSION['textbox'.$i])){
    echo "<strong>".$i."</strong> ".$_SESSION['textbox'.$i]."<br>";//Use the session variables
  }
}
session_destroy();
```

?>